# setting a new variable to each binding of an item in the list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-databinding

I can pass a resource to layout by binding a method call which returns the drawable int (R.drawable).

I want to do it by binding the variable itself onto the layout.

ListFragment.java

```
  public void bindVariables(ListViewBinding binding) {

     // trying to bind this variable onto layout
     int drawableInt = 0;
     binding.setVariable(drawableInt, R.drawable.item1Image);

     binding.setmyService(this.myService);

  }
```

ItemInList.xml

```
 <data>
    <variable name="drawbleInt" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="myService" type="com.myService"/>
 </data>

  **// trying to use the variable set in fragment **

 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcVector="@{ drawableInt}"/>

**//this works - using service variable**

 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcVector="@{ myService.drawableInt()}"/>
```

app:srcVector is a @bindingAdapter to set drawable image to the view.

DataBindingAdapter class

```
@BindingAdapter("app:srcVector") 
 public static void setSrcVector(ImageView view, @DrawableRes int drawable){
   view.setImageResource(drawable);
 }
```

Comment: what is `srcVector`?

Comment: a binding adapter to set drawable image to the view

Comment: whats wrong with `android:src`?

Comment: to set image for each item in a list, the binding adapter is created, like a custom data binding adapter for list

Comment: are you using `support-vector-drawable`? if so, it will not work as you cannot pass `R.drawable.some_vector` to `setImageResource` method

Comment: sorry, I have an additional setter method there in as well, which takes drawable and sets to view. setSrcVetcor(ImageView i, Drawable drawable)

Comment: man, post your code you are working with, the first will not even compile: `view.setImageResource(drawable);` if `drawable` is `Drawable drawable` - it should be `setImageDrawable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145475/discussion-between-rk-reddy-bairi-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the variable with id 0, but this does not identify the variable you want to set.

```
 int drawableInt = 0;
 binding.setVariable(drawableInt, R.drawable.item1Image);
```

Instead you'd have to use `setDrawableInt()` or use the correct id of the variable `BR.drawableInt`.

```
 binding.setDrawableInt(R.drawable.item1Image);
 binding.setVariable(BR.drawableInt, R.drawable.item1Image);
```

Comment: Variable identity (BR) is what I was looking for, thanks